# dose spark Accumulator lead to saveAsTextFile() into one partition?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

I defined a function:

```scala
 def setJsonPushIndex(spark: SparkSession, currentdate: String, jsonPushInfo: RDD[(String, String)]): RDD[String] =
      {
        val sc = spark.sparkContext
        val acc = new LongAccumulator()
        sc.register(acc, "myaccumulator")
        val jsonPushWithIndex = jsonPushInfo.map(x =>
        {
          acc.add(1)
          val sendhour = x._2.toString
          val index = pushUtil.toIndex(acc.value.toString)
          var mid = "BI" + currentdate + sendhour + index
          if (sendhour.toInt < pushUtil.getNextHour().toInt)
          { 
            mid = "BI" + pushUtil.getNextday() + sendhour + index
          }
          mid + "\u0001" +
            "\"mid\": " + "\"" + mid + "\"," +
            x._1
        }
        )
        jsonPushWithIndex
      }
```

then I call in the main function:

```scala
 val json_push_res = setJsonPushIndex(spark, currentdate, json_pushInfo)
    val jsonResultPath= "/jc/algorithm/NewUserPushTest/results/" + pushUtil.NowDate() + "/"
    json_push_res.take(12).foreach(println)
    json_push_res.saveAsTextFile(jsonResultPath)
```

it turns out there is only one partition in my directory "part-00000".
my command is

```
spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 5G  --driver-memory 10G --class "apppush.NewUserPush_V2"  /home/ilambda/lyj/test2.jar
```

the result number is about 30000.

Is the result number is small so as there is one partition at last or `Accumulator` lead to this result?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `Accumulators` doesn't affect the `DAG` and therefore doesn't cause shuffling or coalescing.

Because `jsonPushInfo` is processed using only a narrow transformation

```
jsonPushInfo.map(x =>
  ...
)
```

it doesn't change the number of partitions either.

Therefore we can conclude that `jsonPush` had only one partition from the beginning.

Comment: could us help me with my partition problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813180/read-use-spark-phoenix-from-table-to-rdd-partition-number-is-1