# read use spark phoenix from table to rdd partition number is 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

When I ran my spark code:

```
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
    val noact_table = primaryDataProcessor.getTableData(sqlContext, zookeeper, tableName)
    println("noact_table.rdd:"+noact_table.rdd.partitions.size)
    val tmp = noact_table.rdd
    println(tmp.partitions.size)
    val out = tmp.map(x => x(0) + "," + x(1))
    HdfsOperator.writeHdfsFile(out, "/tmp/test/push")
```

getTableData:

```
 def getTableData(sqlContext: SQLContext, zkUrl: String, tableName: String): DataFrame = {
    val tableData = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
      .option("table", tableName)
      .option("zkUrl", zkUrl).load()
    tableData
  }
```

My problem is the table has about 2000 rows of data,but my partition result in 1[image]

then i continue with :

```
val push_res = cookieRdd.keyBy(_._2._2).join(tmp).map(x => (x._2._1._1, x._1, x._2._2._2, x._2._2._3, x._2._2._4, x._2._2._5, nexthour))
```

My `cookierdd` partition is 96 and the `tmp` partition number is 1
then the number of `push_res`'partition is 1 .
could any when explain why this happen? why `tmp` partition and `push_res` partition are both 1?